# QGIS 3.6 3D View: Data defined override (expression) button is missing

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, 3d

I am trying to create a 3D View in QGIS 3.6.0, but the buttons for data defined parameters (e.g., width or height) are missing in the Layer Properties dialog (see screenshow below)

[image: screenshot layer properties]

I want to set the extrusion and width of my Line geometries according to feature attributes.

Can this be a bug, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data defined override (expression) button is not supported in polyline and point layers, but available in polygon layer:

For Polygon:

[image]

For Polyline:

[image]

For Point:

[image]

This means you cannot use Data defined override (expression) for your line layer.

Comment: Thanks, I thought so, although I do not fully understand the reason for this. My use case would be the visualization of traffic flows in a street network.

Comment: I also do not know the reason. Maybe it will be added in the future since 3D rendering is new to QGIS 3.

Comment: Here's the github commit that added the data-defined polygon heights: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/5515d68219c565220347036645e4b5b61cd9187c Maybe this is a roadmap for how to add it for other geometries.